# JQuery jCarouselLite plugin with fade effect

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

Greetings to all...

I want to use fade effect with  jCarouselLite qualities. Is it possible.

Needs:

1. The image transition time should be fast.
2. Image has to stay for 10 seconds.

Can anyone guid me for this please.

Geetha.

Comment: Then maybe consider at least giving me an upvote for all the effort

Comment: Is there any other plugin support this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Umm... maybe I misunderstand what you want. But what of the things you requested isn't already supported by jCarousel Lite?

- Fade effect: Use the `easing` option (You need to include the [jQuery easing plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/)). Check the [Custom Animation - Easing Demo](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite) (on the right side of the page)
- Fast transition: `speed` option (milliseconds) determines how fast the transition is animated
- Show image for 10 seconds: `auto` option. This way the carousel autoscrolls and the time you specify in milliseconds is the time between two consecutive slides

---

Check a demo here: http://jsbin.com/etena/ (Watch the code here http://jsbin.com/etena/edit)

Comment: I didnt get the fade effect. :(

Comment: Is it possible to get the fade effect in jCarouselLite which is available in cycle plugin

Comment: I don't know. You could look at the code of the cycle plugin and try to port the fade effect to jCarouselLite. Otherwise I guess it won't work

Comment: Thanks for that demo, it's a million times easier to tinker with than jcarousellite's (messy) site..

Answer (score 6):

To fade from "Image to Image" rather than "Image to White to Image" you should set the speed attribute to zero, e.g.

```
$('#content .slider .inner')
    .jCarouselLite(
    {
        afterEnd    : function(el) { $(el).parent().fadeTo(500, 1); },
        beforeStart : function(el) { $(el).parent().fadeTo(500, 0); },
        speed       : 0
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. With easing you can only set the method in which it slides, but jCarousselLite will always slide.

Ofcourse you can change the plugins' default behaviour to match your specific needs. Example here: http://snipplr.com/view/18326/jcarousellite-fade-animation/ (I didn't test this, but looks ok)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with easing. Building on/simplifying what publicJorn wrote, here's a way to add fadeIn/FadeOut effect on sliding:

```
$('div#foo').jCarouselLite({
    visible: 1,
    start: 0,
    beforeStart: function(a) {
            $(a).parent().fadeTo(500, 0);
    },
    afterEnd: function(a) {
            $(a).parent().fadeTo(500, 1);
    }
});
```

Comment: I am not the TS, but is it possible to fade from image to image? Now it's fading from image to white to image.

Comment: possible but you need to manually overlap images during the transition (and making the top one fade out should do the job)